# Angularjs state routing issue in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, angular-ui-router

When application loads index page it successfully routes to the page. But registering two times same url in browser history. So, Browser back button not navigating properly.

Comment: It's possible that you are somehow doing a redirect to the home page as well. Is it doing the same in Chrome?

Comment: No, In chrome, It works fine.

Comment: Do you have some code to look at ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: yes, I found out. I've used iframe that content is loaded from some external url. So, firefox registered url same url twices in history.